# How do I fetch a link to a custom taxonomies page for a custom post type. (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I have set up a feed in a larger page template the lists the most recent posts from a custom post type and belong to a custom taxonomy

e.g. (in this case) a feed listing the most recent video testimonials. (custom post type = testimonials, custom taxonomy = testimonials_cat, slug = video).

I want to add a link that says “view all video testimonials” which would link to a ‘taxonomies-testimonials_cat.php’ (that I’ve already created) displaying all video testimonials.

My question is how do I generate the link? And where do I  put it?

From a design point of view I would like the link to be placed directly after section `<h3>title</h3>` (where i have marked in the code `<?php GET_LINK_TO_ARCHIVE_PAGE ?>`).

Thanks

Here is my code for the WP_Query loop and HTML:

```
<!-- VIDEO TESTIMONIALS -->    
    <div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><h3><?php the_field('title_2'); ?></h3>
                <a href="<?php GET_LINK_TO_ARCHIVE_PAGE ?>">View all video testimonials...</a>
        </div></div>
    <div class="row">
        <!-- VIDEO ARGS -->
        <?php 
        $args = array(
            'post_type'     => 'testimonials',
            'tax_query'     => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'testimonials_cat',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => 'video'
                        )),
            'orderby'       => 'date',
            'posts_per_page' => 4
        );
        $videos = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

        <!-- VIDEO FEED -->
        <?php if ( $videos->have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php while ( $videos->have_posts() ) : $videos->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="post-wrapper  testimonials video col-sm-3" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                    <h2 class="post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <?php the_field('video'); ?>
                </div><!-- end of post wrapper -->
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        <!-- if no post found -->
        <?php else: ?>
          <div class="col-md-12"><h3><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></h3></div>
        <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
        <!--/ end of WP loop -->            
   </div><!-- end of row -->
   <hr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use **[get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy )](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link)** function.

In your case, this should work:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_term_link( 'video', 'testimonials_cat' ); ?>">
    View all video testimonials...
</a>
```

Comment: It hasn't worked. The outputted anchor link doesn't have an href. In other words it doesn't seem to have done anything. Do I need to define the term or something first?

Comment: Ok it worked, I just had to add 'echo' to actually print out the url I guess. `<?php echo get_term_link( 'video', 'testimonials_cat' ); ?>`

Comment: @user3446373, indeed! I forgot the `echo`. I edited my answer.